# PHP 7.2 deprecated each to foreach not working

Tags: php

I'm trying to change from each to foreach but I cannot get it to work.

I keep getting an error saying PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ')' but there is no unexpected ')' ????

Thanks for any help!

```
    // Splits textarea lines into an array.
    $newEntry = explode("\n",$txtarea);

    // Obtain the number of new entries.
    $x = 0;
    while (each($newEntry)) {
        $x++;
    } 
    reset($newEntry);

//---------------------------------------------------

    if ($_POST['groups']) {
        while (list ($x_key, $x_gid) = each ($_POST['groups'])) {
            $groupsql = "INSERT INTO " . TABLE_GROUPS . " VALUES ($id,$x_gid)";
            runQuery($groupsql);
        }
    }
```

**THIS IS WHAT IS  IN THE POST**

```
Array ( [id] => 44 [lastname] => Anderson [firstname] => John [middlename] => William [address_zip_0] => 9922 
[nickname] => Will [address_state_0] => Denver, CO [x_gid] => 123T [pictureURL] => pixtest.jpg 
[address_type_0] => testtype [address_primary_select] => test field address primary [address_line1_0] => 2 [address_city_0] => denver
[address_phone1_0] => 111-222-3333 [address_email] => test@test.com [address_phone2_0] => 999-888-7777 [status2] => [notes] => test 1122 
[address_websites] => www.test.com [address_additionaldata] => [groups] => Array ( [0] => 55 ) [address_type_1] => [address_line1_1] => 
[address_line2_1] => [address_city_1] => [address_state_1] => [address_zip_1] => [address_phone1_1] => [address_phone2_1] => [addnum] => 1 )
```

Comment: `$x = count($newEntry);`

Comment: @AlexHowansky what about  while (list ($x_key, $x_gid) = each ($_POST['groups'])) {  .... keeps saying syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH) if I change it to while (list ($x_key, $x_gid) = foreach ($_POST['groups'])) { ... Thanks again for your help

Comment: `foreach` and `each` do different things and have different syntax, you can't just interchange them. Read the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Comment: Never include a $_POST value directly into your query. It's prone to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($_POST['groups']) {
        while (list ($x_key, $x_gid) = each ($_POST['groups'])) {
            $groupsql = "INSERT INTO " . TABLE_GROUPS . " VALUES ($id,$x_gid)";
            runQuery($groupsql);
        }
    }
```

converted to use `foreach()`

```
if ($_POST['groups']) {
        foreach($_POST['groups'] as $g) {
            $groupsql = "INSERT INTO " . TABLE_GROUPS . " VALUES ({$_POST['id']},$g)";
            runQuery($groupsql);
        }
    }
```

notes:

-- huge security issue with raw post values going in to db like this

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I keep getting an error saying: "Illegal string offset 'id'" and "Illegal string offset 'x_gid'" ... any ideas ? I am new to PHP, sorry for this.

Comment: @compcobalt "array keys from post are guessed as you did not specify them" you need to change to your array keys, i dont know what they are (you can check with `print_r($_POST);`)

Comment: they are just numbers both of them

Comment: @compcobalt not sure what you mean by that, could you post the result of `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: Hi, Thanks .... Check out the edited question. I added it there for better formatting.

Comment: @compcobalt i have updated the answer, the dump of post made it clear what you wanted